# How is pground metric (to measure percent ground hits) implemented into function for grid_metrics in lidR?

Tags: lidr

I'm having difficulty with the method to obtain the percentage of points classified as ground using `grid_metrics()`. I would like to implement pground (one metric) like `stdmetrics` (a set of metrics), but can't see how.

Does it have to be set up in a custom function instead?

The reference I'm using:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lidR/versions/3.1.0/topics/stdmetrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what your problem is. If the following does not anwser your question please edit your question to clarify.

```r
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile)
pground <- grid_metrics(las, ~sum(Classification == LASGROUND)/.N*100, 10)
```

```r
plot(pground, col = gray.colors(50))
```

[image]